# Can no longer build Confluence plugin

Tags: maven, confluence, cargo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

At work I help to develop a Confluence plugin. Current software versions (and I believe the latest we can currently use, because reasons), according to `atlas-version`, are:

```
ATLAS Version:    8.2.7
ATLAS Maven Home: /Users/cabenso/dev/atlassian-sdk/apache-maven-3.5.4
AMPS Version:     8.1.2
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T19:33:14+01:00)
Java version: 1.8.0_351, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Default locale: en_IE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.3.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

It was all going swimmingly until around the time I upgraded my MacBook Pro to 10.13.1. Since then, `atlas-run` produces the following errors a few minutes into the build:

```
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Deployable [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
[ERROR] Starting container [org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat9xInstalledLocalContainer@759d44a3] failed, now stopping container
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 9.x is stopping...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1g; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 24, 2023 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Could not contact [localhost:65296] (base port [65296] and offset [0]). Tomcat may not be running.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 24, 2023 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Error stopping Catalina
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:513)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:389)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:479)
```

and when the build completes a few minutes later:

```
[INFO] confluence: Shutting down
[INFO] using codehaus cargo v1.6.10
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 9.x is stopping...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 9.x is stopped
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-24T12:30:03+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:confluence-maven-plugin:8.1.0:run (default-cli) on project producthub: Cannot start container [org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat9xInstalledLocalContainer@759d44a3]: Deployable [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown. -> [Help 1]
```

None of us can figure out what's wrong and how to fix it, and nobody else in our team seems to be having the issue. Apart from extensive Googling, I've:

- Rebooted (of course, many times)
- Run clean builds with `atlas-clean`
- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled Java and the Atlassian SDK
- Temporarily uninstalled our mandatory anti-virus and firewall software (yes, I know - gotta love big corporations)

but so far nothing has made any difference.

It doesn't even appear to be possible to modify the timeout I'm hitting, to see if that helps anything. Or at least, there are no occurrences of `timeout` or `600000` in any of the project config files, and Atlassian's [official answer](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/product-fails-to-start-within-timeout-period/) appears to be 'make your build run quicker so it doesn't time out'.

I can still build the plugin itself (using `atlas-package`) and deploy it to our staging servers for testing, but that is obviously a lot less safe and convenient than being able to test it locally.

Any suggestions for other things to try?

Answer (score 0):

SDK 8.2.7 supports Java 11 so you can try to set Target/Source in Maven to 11 and use OpenJDK or AdoptOpenJDK and compile with these options. Also, make sure to use the SDK maven and not old caches of SDK maven.

Comment: Thanks, been off work for a couple of weeks but will try this later.